# how to connect to local network from kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, local-network, helm3

I have a k8s cluster set up on a few raspberry pis for local development. I am trying to use a database running in the local network however I can't seem to get the pods to connect to the db. I have tried using a service and endpoint configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.database.host }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-2"
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.database.port }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.database.host }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-2"
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: {{ .Values.database.ip }}
    ports:
      - port: {{ .Values.database.port }}
        name: {{ .Values.database.host }}
```

I can confirm that the endpoint and service resources are created and that all the connection details are correct but my application (running on the k8s cluster) still will not connect to the database on the host network. Reading the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) closer it sounds like these resources are for connecting to the cluster from the local network, not the other way around? Is there a way to connect to services on a local network from k8s resources?

result of running `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

```
local-path-provisioner-5ff76fc89d-txj6k   1/1     Running   4          65d
metrics-server-86cbb8457f-r8q6w           1/1     Running   3          65d
coredns-7448499f4d-5646n                  1/1     Running   10         176d
csi-smb-node-9j5gm                        3/3     Running   3291       150d
csi-smb-controller-6c696945f8-8t6qj       3/3     Running   27         150d
csi-smb-controller-6c696945f8-ck5hh       3/3     Running   3361       150d
csi-smb-node-822bb                        3/3     Running   3260       150d
csi-smb-node-4nckf                        3/3     Running   3655       150d
```

Comment: Does your client runs in the cluster network or on the host network?

Comment: the client is in the cluster network, the db is on the host network

Comment: The host which the database runs on is one of the worker node and you can ping the host from a pod within the cluster? Or the host is **not** part of the cluster?

Comment: the db is running on one of the raspberry pis that the k8s nodes are running on. I can access the db from any of the raspberry pis when I ssh into them, so I know they are accessable via the host network. I am trying to figure out how to bridge the k8s and host network so that the k8s pods can call the db running on the host network.

Comment: The CNI should have provided that. What CNI are you using and you have checked the CNI pods are free of error?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have added the result of running `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` to the question. which from my understanding from googling should contain the CNI, however full disclosure I hadn't heard of CNI before you mentioned it.

Comment: `kubectl run ping --image busybox --restart Never -it --rm -- ping <host IP>` - is the ping successful?

Comment: yes it appears to work

Comment: Ok, about `...can't seem to get the pods to connect to the db`, what's the error are you getting?

Comment: normal connection error within the pod, `Error: ConfigError: Cannot connect to postgres database with connection string: "postgres://user:password@host-ip:5432/dbname". Do the database & user exist?`

Comment: the values have been replaced with dummy values but I can connect with the exact same connection string using psql from any of the raspberry pis when I ssh into them

Comment: It's only counted if the `psql` was executed in a pod (like the ping), not on the host.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean when you say "it's only counted"?

Comment: Something like this: `kubectl run psql --image postgre:<version> --restart Never --image-pull-policy IfNotPresent -it --rm -- psql -h <host IP> -U <user> -W <database name>`. See if you can successfully connect to the PostgreSQL on the host.

Comment: i get a longer error: `psql: error: connection to server at "host", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host  "host", user "user", database "adbname", SSL on
connection to server at "host", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "host", user "user", database "dbname", SSL off
pod default/postgres terminated (Error)`

Comment: This is a famous postgresql configuration error, you are sure to find lots of solutions on the web like this [one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host).

Comment: @MarcusRuddick Have you resolved your question?

Comment: yes, but there was no answer to chose as a solution. I will add what I did to fix my issue, however I don't believe the solution is related to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was not a kubernetes one, but a configuration issue. I was able to solve the problem I was experiencing by modifying the postgres hba configuration file to have a broader range of ip addresses. As mentioned by @gohm'c there are many resources online describing how to fix the connection error that I was encountering. Thanks to @gohm'c for their help in debugging.